# How do I do two consequent HTTP requests in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am using Jmeter to stress test my website.

Each user needs to make two requests consecutively:

1. First request to a auto-login page.
2. Second request to an internal page.

How can I tell Jmeter to make these two requests in that order for each thread?

Comment: I meant I need first to login to get authenticated session and later go to target page. If two requests are executed separately it is not possible to get the authorized session.

Answer (score 13):

Take a look at order execution in the [User Manual](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/test_plan.html)

Jmeter will run the requests in the order you place them.  So your structure would look like this:

```
Test Plan
 + ThreadGroup
   + HTTP Request - LOGIN
   + HTTP Request - 2nd Page
```

In addition to reading the usermanual, also check out the official [step-by-step guide on how to record](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)

Comment: Yes, this is the actual fact: Jmeter will run the requests in the order you place them.

Comment: Does not work for me: the response from the first request (login) shows me, that it logged in successfully, but the second request is redirected to login page as well. :/

Comment: So, that's a problem with your login session, not your request orders.  Most likely you aren't storing a login cookie or other data needed to maintain your session.   I'd recommend going through the tutorials on how to do so.